# C# (XNA Game Studio) Getting offscreen objects to not render

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, xna, render

I am currently developing a game for windows phone 7. The map for my game consists of a 2 dimensional array that holds a voxel in each element. The code for the rendering of the map is as follows.

```
//Draw Map
for (int i = 0; i < 499; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 499; j++)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(groundVoxelTexture, voxels[i, j].Position, Color.White);
    }
}
```

I should also mention that the player stays centered on the screen and the map moves around the player.

The problem is that this creates A LOT of textures for the phone to render and ends up causing so much lag that the phone I run it on locks up. So is there a way to make the objects that are off screen not render?

Comment: I'm not familiar with XNA, but performance-wise, it's generally a good idea to batch all the sprites you intend to draw into one call. Here you're drawing each individually every draw cycle. That's a lot of calls.

Comment: I assume that the positions are in an order of some sort? you should just be able to adjust your loop start and end positions

Comment: @ErikN spriteBatch has a `Begin` and an `End` that you must call. I'm not 100% sure, but I bet it batches them together into one call when `End` is called.

Comment: @Cemafor Ah, that would make sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to do some [Frustum Culling](http://www.andrejeworutzki.de/game-developement/xna-4-tutorial-frustum-and-occlusion-culling/)

I'm not familier with xna for a phone app, but I'm sure it's the same proccess.

```
//Draw Map
BoundingFrustum bf = new BoundingFrustum(View * Projection);
for (int i = 0; i < 499; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 499; j++)
    {
        if (bf.Intersects(new BoundingSphere(voxels[i, j].Position, voxelRadius)))
            spriteBatch.Draw(groundVoxelTexture, voxels[i, j].Position, Color.White);
    }
}
```

If the view stays in place and the map moves around, you should be able to use the same BoundingFrustum from frame to frame.

Comment: I like your approach, BoundingFrustum is something I had never heard of before and would simply my logic alot

Answer (score 0):

Using boundingfrustum is a bit hardcore in this situation.

is much better calculate the grid indexes that need to be drawn.

you are using spritebatch so you are working in 2D, the easy to me would be to use a view transform and work with it inverse to get indexes, but  I think you are not using it.

So I suppose that your voxels have a size "S" and your player is in position P, and the screen has size (W,H) and there is no zoom option.

```
MinX= (int) ((P.X - W * 0.5) / S) - 1;
MinY= (int) ((P.Y - H * 0.5) / S) - 1;
MaxX= MinX+ W/S + 2;
MaxY= MinY+ H/S + 2;

for (int i = MinX; i < MaxX; i++)
{
    for (int j = MinY; j < MaxY; j++)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(groundVoxelTexture, voxels[i, j].Position, Color.White);
    }
}
```